# OpenMP has low CPU usage

Tags: c++, openmp, cpu-usage

My OpenMP Implementation shows a really bad performance. When I profile it with vtune, I have a super low CPU usage and I don't know why. Does anyone have an idea?

Hardware:

- NUMA architecture with 28 cores (56 Threads)

Implementation:

```
struct Lineitem {
    int64_t l_quantity;
    int64_t l_extendedprice;
    float l_discount;
    unsigned int l_shipdate;
};

Lineitem* array = (Lineitem*)malloc(sizeof(Lineitem) * array_length);
```

// array will be filled

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(48) shared(array, array_length, date1, date2) reduction(+: sum)
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < array_length; i++)
{
     if (array[i].l_shipdate >= date1 && array[i].l_shipdate < date2 &&
         array[i].l_discount >= 0.08f && array[i].l_discount <= 0.1f &&
         array[i].l_quantity < 24)
         {
              sum += (array[i].l_extendedprice * array[i].l_discount);
         }
}
```

Additionally as information, I am using cmake and clang.

Comment: how low is "super low" ? What is the size of the array? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: The array has a size of 1,8 GB with 6 millions elements and every OMP Worker Thread has a maximum cpu time of 3 %.

Comment: How slow is the code? With 1.8GB of data and fairly simple operations you might be running into memory bandwidth or cache contention issues

Comment: What compile options did you use?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number In my minimal reproducible example, my problems do not occur. Therefore, I think it will not be helpful if I post the minimal example. But very good to know that it is not because of the OpenMP implementation.

Comment: @AlanBirtles What do you mean with "How slow is the code"? Do you want to have a time how long it takes?

Comment: @Homer512 I am using the C++ flag "-fopenmp=libomp" and I link the openmp library with the target_link_libraries() command.

Comment: @Tored reduction is an inherently serial operation. You may be better off trading memory to precalc things and then do a quick linear sum operation, believe it or not the CPU is really really good at doing things like that. This isn't an answer (hence not posted as one) just an observation. Also be wary of branch mispredict

Comment: @Mgetz Reduction is not serial. Each thread uses its own accumulator which are then summed up at the end of the loop in a treewise fashion. So it's almost perfectly parallel.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout you may wish to check the godbolt output... it's very very much serial and uses the lock prefix at least on GCC

Comment: @Mgetz Maybe it uses an atomic for the final reduction, when adding one value per thread to the final result. But the loop itself will use a private copy per thread and not use a lock prefix.

Comment: @Mgetz For reference: https://godbolt.org/z/7d65Wah6n The body of the if statement starts is line 144-149. The final reduction is 154-158

Comment: GCC is a notoriously bad compiler for OpenMP. Use the Intel compiler or LLVM.

Comment: @Mgetz GCC use a lock but only for the final reduction (outside the hot loop). Most of the work is done in each thread in parallel. The lock should be done 48 times here so it should not be a problem unless the OP operate on a pretty small array (which would be a very bad idea). The lock will be significantly slower on NUMA systems due to a cache line bouncing effect and remote RFOs. But again, this should be cheap on large arrays.

Comment: Please add more information about the array size and more specifically profiling information (or if possible a fully reproducible example). The low CPU usage could be due to swap memory being used for example (please check the disk usage). Alternatively, if the array is too small, most of the time could be spent in OpenMP overheads. NUMA effects can also create a load imbalance (due to local access being faster). How `array` is distributed amongst the NUMA nodes? Did you care about this? Many critical informations are missing so to help you further. Please update the question with them.

Comment: yes, how long does it take to execute. Slow could mean "50ms but you want it to execute in 20ms" but 50ms would be quite fast for processing nearly 2gb of data

Comment: @AlanBirtles The slow code took nearly 1 second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the cause of my poor OpenMP performance. I am running my OpenMP code inside a thread pinned to a core. If I don't pin the thread to a core, then the OpenMP code is fast.

Probably the threads created by OpenMP in the pinned thread are also executed on the core where the pinned thread is pinned. Consequently, the whole OpenMP code runs on only one core with many threads.

Comment: This is why we ask for a [mre] there's no way anybody could have arrived at this answer from the information in your question

Comment: @AlanBirtles You're right. It won't happen again that I create a post without a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: What do I need to do to check this on my setup? I am experiencing a similar scenario. I checked the affinity of the process in Windows Task Manager, and its set to use all processors. Its CPU utilization is still low, around 15%.

Comment: I looked at it in a profiler and saw there on which threads my program was running. That the thread (through which I started the OpenMP code) was pinned to a core, I knew because I could see it in the code.

Comment: In my case, I did not know that I needed to add -fopenmp during compilation to compile openmp code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Modern CPUs will only show high performance if there is lots of cache data to be reused. Since you are only operating linearly on an array, there is no such thing and you are limited by memory bandwdith. Your cores will indeed be operating at a small fraction of their full utilization.

Things may be even worse: you have an array of structures from which you use certain fields. If there are other fields that you don't use,  you get the phenomenon that you don't fully use the cachelines that you load from memory, dividing the performance yet again by a factor. Please amend your question by including the data layout of your structure/class.

Comment: Even if all threads are bound by memory bandwidth, they should still show up as 100% loaded. Maybe not at full frequency, but still 100% CPU utilization. Or does vtune use a metric that actually takes port utilization and other microarchitectonical state into account?

Comment: @Homer512 I do not know what metric vtune uses

Comment: But shouldn't I get a better runtime by parallel computation compared to serial execution, independent of the cache usage?

Comment: @Tored not always spinning up threads can take longer than just doing the work, particularly if you can vectorize it

Comment: @Homer512 [This](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/reference/cpu-metrics-reference.html) says about CPU time: "CPU Time is time during which the CPU is actively executing your application.". Not sure how this translates to a percentage though... There is also a "CPU Utilization" metric.

Comment: if you are memory bandwidth limited then adding CPU cores could actually make the code slower due to sharing of the memory controller(s) between cores and contention in shared caches

Comment: @paleonix thanks for looking this up. That metric cannot differentiate between a CPU stalling because it's waiting for responses from main memory and one that is active doing computations. From the docs, the "Cache Bound" metric and CPI could be good indicators to see what the actual issue is here. Branch Mispredict would also be very interesting because we deal with a massive if statement

Comment: @Homer512 only that OP seems to have solved his problem...